# Save the results of every iteration in the same data frame

Tags: r

In a loop what is the best way to save the results of every iteration a dataframe?

The column names are always the same but the rbind has a problem that row names are duplicates

I tried cbind, rbind and merge but anyting worked.

Example:

```
dfiteration <- data.frame()

dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), other = c(1,4))

for (i in 1:3) {

dframe1 <- dframe

dfiteration <- rbind(dfiteration, dframe1)
}
```

Comment: what does `names(x$otherPkgs)` give you?

Comment: @CatalystRPA it gives `NULL`

Comment: i can't reproduce the error. if you get the error with your setup just restart r/rstudio

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me. Surely you didn't give the data to reproduce your error.

Try using `dfiteration <- base::rbind(dfiteration, dframe1)` to ensure that `rbind` is not being masked by another package you have loaded. You could also post the entire results of `sessionInfo()` so we can check what R version and packages are around.

In parallel, change the `make.row.names` argument to `FALSE` within `rbind` and that might work.

```
dfiteration <- base::rbind(dfiteration, dframe1, make.row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save each dataframe separately, you can store the iterations in a list:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), other = c(1,4))
mylist <- list()

for (i in 1:3){
  dframe1 <- dframe
  mylist[[i]] <- dframe1
}
```